# Solve $x^2+(-7-4i)x+9+15i=0.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $$x^2+(-7-4i)x+9+15i=0.$$

Using the quadratic formula, I get $$\frac12 (7+4i \pm \sqrt{-4i})$$ but that's not correct. How do you solve this? I get no help from looking at wolfram alpha.

Comment: $-4i = [\sqrt{2}(-1+i)]^2$

Comment: the discriminant is $\sqrt{-3-4i}$

Comment: $$x=\frac{7+4i}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{(7+4i)^2-9-15i}}{2}$$ and $$(7+4i)^2-9-15i=-4i$$

Comment: @jacob No, the radical term is
$$\sqrt{b^2-\color{red}{4}ac} = \sqrt{(-7-4i)^2 - 4(9+15i)} = \sqrt{-3-4i}$$
as Suraj M.S said.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

$$x^2+(-7-4i)x+(9+15i) = 0$$

We use the well known formula to find
$$\begin{align}
x & = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4 \cdot a \cdot c}}{2  \cdot a} \\
  & = \frac{-(-7-4i)\pm \sqrt{(-7-4i)^2 - 4 \cdot 1 \cdot (9+15i)}}{2  \cdot 1} \\
  & = \frac{7+4i \pm\sqrt{(49 + 56i -16) - (36+60i)}}{2} \\
  & = \frac{7+4i \pm\sqrt{-3 - 4i}}{2} \\
\end{align}$$

Now to find $\sqrt{-3 - 4i}$ we note that this can expressed as $r (\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ where $r = \sqrt{3^2 +4^2}$ and $\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-3}{-4}\right)$.

$\sqrt{r (\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)} = \pm \sqrt{r} \cdot \left( \cos \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)  + i \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \right)$

Alternatively if you are not using a calculator we need to find $a + bi$ such that $(a+bi)^2 = -3 -4i$

Note: $(a + bi)^2 = (a^2 - b^2) + 2 \cdot a \cdot b \cdot i$

We therefore have two simultaneous equations to solve:

$a^2 - b^2 = -3$ and $2 \cdot a \cdot b = -4 \Rightarrow a \cdot b = -2$

Ignoring the signs we can see that $|b| \gt |a|$ as the the real part is negative and $a$ and $b$ must have opposite signs as the imaginary part is negative. A little trial and error should show you that $(1 - 2i)$ and $(-1 + 2i)$ are solutions to $\sqrt{-3-4i}$

I'm sure you can take it from there.

Comment: I can't do $\arctan(3/4)$

Comment: Its approx 36.8699 degrees or 0.64350 radians. If that helps

Comment: I'm not allowed to use a calculator, so is there another way?

Comment: @jacob I've added that to my answer.

Comment: I solved it now using another method, 

1. Re(x) the same (comparing a with  the right side)
2. Im(x) the same (comparing b with  the right side)
3. Abs(x) the same ((comparing $a^2-b^2$ with  the right side)

Answer (score 1):

the discriminant in your question is $\sqrt{-3-4i}$
furhter simplify the term inside the square root in the form
$$r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
taking square root changes it to
$$\sqrt{r}(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2})$$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have used the quadratic formula incorrectly.

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}$$

gives,

$$x=\frac{7+4i\pm\sqrt{(7+4i)^2-36-60i}}{2}$$

$$x=\frac{7+4i\pm\sqrt{-3-4i}}{2}$$

Now try to find the value of $\sqrt{-3-4i}$. Let, $a+bi=\sqrt{-3-4i}$ and try to solve this to find the values of $a$ and $b$.